# getting Wicket.Event is undefined for wicketAjaxGet()

Tags: java, javascript, wicket, undefined

I'm trying to make an user login to facebook via the javascript sdk. The code for the auth.login is:

```
Label loginEvent = new Label("loginEvent", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
    public String getObject() {
        return "FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) " +
        "{" +
        "alert('Finalmente, logado!');" +
        "var wcall = wicketAjaxGet('" + loginBehavior.getCallbackUrl() +
        "&fbid='+ response.authResponse.userID +'" +
        "&accessToken='+ response.authResponse.accessToken +'" +
        "',function() { }, function() { });" +
        "alert('Chamou o behavior!');" +
        "});";
    }
});

loginEvent.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
loginEvent.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(loginEvent);
```

The html counterpart for the label is:

```
<script wicket:id="loginEvent"></script>
```

When I login to facebook, only the first alert is displayed. I never get to call wicketAjaxGet(). Firebug gives me these two errors and Firefox compiles those script tags (wicket-event returns unreadable):

```
Wicket.Event is undefined
[Break On This Error]
Wicket.Browser is undefined
[Break On This Error]   
<script type="text/javascript" src="wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WicketEventReference/wicket-event-ver-1327971835000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.WicketAjaxReference/wicket-ajax-ver-1327971835000.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/wicket-ajax-debug-ver-1327971835000.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just fixed it. There was a malformed script tag just above the wicket-event tag that was rendering it unreadable. Silly mistake, maybe this'll help someone who runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a wicketstuff lib for facebook. https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Facebook